# Словесное написание имён, прозвищ, кличек и т. п., которые изначально написаны цифрами и буквами

Tags: прописная-строчная, ономастика, дефис-тире, цифры, буквы

Скажите, если имя/прозвище героя написано цифрами и буквами, как правильно записать его в словесном выражении (есть такая необходимость)? У меня три примера.

1. *626* (прозвище Стича из мультфильма "Лило и Стич" ) = *Шесть-Два-Шесть* / *Шесть Два Шесть*?
2. *C-3PО* (дроид из "Звёздных войн") = *Си-Три-Пи-О* / *Си-ТриПиО* / *Си — Три-Пи-О*?..
3. *R2-D2* (дроид из "Звёздных войн") = *Эр-Два-Дэ-Два* /  *ЭрДва-ДэДва* / *Эр-Два — Дэ-Два*?..

Знаю, что каждое слово в прозвище/имени должно писаться с прописной буквы, но как быть с дефисом? Я бы сказал, что самые первые варианты наиболее предпочтительны (Шесть-Два-Шесть, Си-Три-Пи-О, Эр-Два-Дэ-Два), но уверенности нет, поскольку в тех же названиях дроидов дефис используется в конкретных местах (C-3PO, R2-D2), и кажется, что это надо бы учесть в словесном варианте. Но как это сделать, если дефис и так просится между цифрами и буквами? Неужели надо заменить его на тире, как в последних вариантах (Си — Три-Пи-О, Эр-Два — Дэ-Два)?.. Выглядит ужасно, честно говоря. Так как же лучше тогда передать это именно словесно? Какие есть предложения?

**ДОПОЛНЕНО**

"Грамма.ру" ответила так, мол, что в каждом случае словесное написание является авторским решением, с учётом существующих правил.

*Правилами русской орфографии написание подобных имен собственных не регламентируется. Это фантазийные имена, и их графическое оформление представляет собой авторское решение. Безусловно, правила русской орфографии принимаются в таких случаях во внимание, в том числе практика использования в онимах дефиса.
В связи с этим "правильно" записать в ином виде придуманное кем-то имя собственное - значит, по сути, исказить его. Перед читателем может стоять другая проблема - верно произнести такое имя, с учетом традиции произнесения соответствующих букв (как в Ваших примерах, где использованы английские буквы).*

Comment: Правилами такие изыски вряд ли регламентируются. Выберите то написание, какое вам нравится. Главное, чтобы на протяжении редактируемого вами текста написание не менялось, то есть соблюдалось единообразие.

Comment: @Nektoid, думаю, вы правы, и "Грамота.ру" вряд ли ответит (если ответит) как-то сильно иначе. Если хотите, можете оформить ответ, расширив ваш комментарий (если сможете, было бы неплохо пару примеров найти), согласен его принять на основе вашей мысли из комментария.